# Can windows server 2012 R2 operating system be used on vmware? On a windows 10 desktop?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-server-2012-r2

I want to install windows server 2012 R2, the essentials version, on a windows 10 operating system, but I still want to have the windows 10 operating system installed. So I believe the best option would be to use a virtualization tool such as VMWARE.

Comment: .... yes.. or VirtualBox. Based on the title of the question: Any OS can be installed on VMWare/VirtualBox. On any "Host" - win10 can run a VM of a server, or vice versa to your need. So exactly what is your question?

Comment: I see that the windows 10 computer does have Hyper-V, but would 4 GB of RAM be enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can windows server 2012 R2 operating system be used on vmware?

VMWare can run every modern version of Windows that has been released without an issue.

> So I believe the best option would be to use a virtualization tool
>   such as VMWARE.

You could also use Hyper-V or VirtualBox if you so desire.  There are other virtualization software, that I have not listed, which could be used also.

> I see that the windows 10 computer does have Hyper-V, but would 4 GB
>   of RAM be enough?

[System Requirements for Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn383626(v=ws.11).aspx):

> CPU socket: 1.4 GHz (64-bit processor) or faster for single core or
>   1.3 GHz (64-bit processor) or faster for multi-core
>
> Memory (RAM): 2 GB or **4 GB if you deploy Windows Server Essentials as
>   a virtual machine**

If your physical machine only has 4GB then your system does not meet the minimum requirements to run `Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials` within a virtual machine.

Comment: The memory requirements depend on if you're running server core or full GUI.  I have run Windows Server Core 2012 R2 inside Virtualbox with as little as 768 MB of RAM.  Having said that, if you're running any kind of virtualization software on top of Windows 10, you really want 8 GB at a minimum.

Comment: The requirements come straight from Microsoft.  Has anything I said in this answer factually incorrect?  The requirements for Core are clearly different from Essentials

Answer (score 0):

Yes windows server 2012 R2 operating system can be installed in VMWARE box. I am using this setup on my VMware box.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this *does* answer the question, it has already been stated in another more extensive answer *"VMWare can run every modern version of Windows that has been released without an issue"*, so it is not adding anything new of value and only serves to add "noise" to the site.